# CollectionView with JSON Data

Tags: ios, iphone, json, ios7, uicollectionview

i am sending the json and store the values in Collection view the array is showing empty at didSelectItemAtIndexPath Please help me..

```
    NSDictionary * jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    albumImageArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    [albumImageArr addObjectsFromArray:[jsonResult objectForKey:@"photoList"]];

    NSLog(@"Array %@",albumImageArr);

    for (NSDictionary *dic in albumImageArr)
    {

    str1=[dic objectForKey:@"photoURL"];
    [arr addObject:str1];

    }


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView1 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *path = [[albumImageArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photoURL"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    PhotoDescriptionViewController *albumsController = (PhotoDescriptionViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DescriptionView"];

    NSString *senderImg=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    albumsController.receivedImage=senderImg;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:albumsController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Please explain what debugging you have done to try and fix this.

Comment: i am showing image data in cellForRowAtIndexPath. and i want to show the image data in detailedViewController with didSelectItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: So, do you access the same data structure in didSelectItemAtIndexPath?  Don't expect to get the data from the cell, get it from your data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do similar to what you have done in cellForRowAtIndexPath, then set receivedImage of albumsController to the image (assuming receivedImage is a UIImage).

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    PhotoDescriptionViewController *albumsController = (PhotoDescriptionViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DescriptionView"];

    NSString *path = [[albumImageArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photoURL"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    albumsController.receivedImage = image;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:albumsController animated:YES];

}
```

In response to your further queries:
In PhotoDescriptionViewController change receivedImage from a NSString to a UIImage, then in viewWillAppear: (or wherever you set the image), to:

```
imageView.image = receivedImage;
```

Comment: it showing warning like this 
incompatible pointer types assigning to 'nsstring *' from 'uiimage *'

Comment: What type is albumsController.receivedImage?

Comment: receivedImage is NSString Type

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, I would expect it to be a UIImage as that is what it is passing through.

Comment: i want to show image but i took receivedImage as a string

Comment: Why if you want to show an image are you sending through a string? Have you tried changing receivedImage in albumsController to a UIImage?

Comment: i worte this code in photoDescriptionView Controller 
 UIImage * imageDispay=[UIImage imageNamed:receivedImage];
    imageView.image = imageDispay;

Comment: I have added to my answer above.

Comment: What warning, please be more specific?